# Array of classes and methods in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

Okay, so I have a little assignment to do which needs some array of classes and calling various methods to get the job done. Essentially, I am looking to learn a bit through this program as well and the idea of it is to create a customer account, deposit, withdraw etc. I have written this code so far and I am getting the errors that I gave below. Please help me out in any way possible. And is var++ not an allowed option to increment a number in Java??

```
import java.util.*;

public class Bank
    {
        int cId;
        String cName;
        float cBalance;
    }
class Banking
{
public static void main(String args[])
{


    int limit=1;
    System.out.println(+limit);
    while (limit==1)
    {
    System.out.println("Menu:");
    System.out.println("1. Add Customer");
    System.out.println("2. View Customer Details");
    System.out.println("3. Banking Options");
    System.out.println("Enter choice:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int i=scan.nextInt();
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("Add the customer");
                Customer();
            }
        /*case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("Customer details");
                getCustomer();
            }
        case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("Banking options");
                System.out.println("1. Deposit");
                System.out.println("2. Withdraw");
                System.out.println("3. Balance Enquiry");
                Scanner scan1 = new Scanner (System.in);
                int j=scan1.nextInt();
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                                                           System.out.println("Deposit");
                            deposit();
                        }
                    case 2:
                        {
                                                           System.out.println("Withdraw");
                            withdraw();
                        }
                    case 3:
                        {
                                                           System.out.println("Balance Enquiry");
                            balance();
                        }
                }
            }
    }   */
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit or 1 to continue operations");
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    limit=scan.nextInt();
    }
}
}
}
public static void Customer (String []a)
{
    int cust=0;
    Bank c[cust] = new Bank();
    System.out.println("Enter customer ID:");
    Scanner scan11 = new Scanner (System.in);
    int k=scan11.nextInt();
    c[cust].cId=k;
    System.out.println("Enter customer name:");
    Scanner scan12 = new Scanner (System.in);
    String name=scan12.next();
    c[cust].cName=name;
    System.out.println("Enter starting balance:");
    Scanner scan132 = new Scanner (System.in);
    float bal=scan132.nextFloat();
    c[cust].cBalance=bal;

    System.out.print("Customer id=" +c[cust].cId );
    cust++;


}

}
```

And the errors are given here:

```
bank.java:73: class, interface, or enum expected
        public static void Customer (String []a)
                      ^
bank.java:76: class, interface, or enum expected
                Bank c[cust] = new Bank();
                ^
bank.java:77: class, interface, or enum expected
                System.out.println("Enter customer ID:");
                ^
bank.java:78: class, interface, or enum expected
                Scanner scan11 = new Scanner (System.in);
                ^
bank.java:79: class, interface, or enum expected
                int k=scan11.nextInt();
                ^
bank.java:80: class, interface, or enum expected
                c[cust].cId=k;
                ^
bank.java:81: class, interface, or enum expected
                System.out.println("Enter customer name:");
                ^
bank.java:82: class, interface, or enum expected
                Scanner scan12 = new Scanner (System.in);
                ^
bank.java:83: class, interface, or enum expected
                String name=scan12.next();
                ^
bank.java:84: class, interface, or enum expected
                c[cust].cName=name;
                ^
bank.java:85: class, interface, or enum expected
                System.out.println("Enter starting balance:");
                ^
bank.java:86: class, interface, or enum expected
                Scanner scan132 = new Scanner (System.in);
                ^
bank.java:87: class, interface, or enum expected
                float bal=scan132.nextFloat();
                ^
bank.java:88: class, interface, or enum expected
                c[cust].cBalance=bal;
                ^
bank.java:90: class, interface, or enum expected
                System.out.print("Customer id=" +c[cust].cId );
                ^
bank.java:91: class, interface, or enum expected
                cust++;
                ^
bank.java:94: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
17 errors
```

Thanks a lot guys!!

Comment: For one, you need break statements in your switch. Though, this will likely not fix your errors. And yes, var++ is a completely acceptable way to increment a variable by 1 in Java.
And I believe you are getting dependency errors. You should have a Bank class that this program is referring to. If it is homeowork, then it is most likely provided by the professor or you are to define the Bank class yourself.

Comment: Yes, you can increment numbers in java using ++: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Comment: I would start with refactoring your one class file into three separate class files, one for each class.  Breaking up the problem may help you solve it (or at least narrow down your compilation errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

```
bank.java:73: class, interface, or enum expected
        public static void Customer (String []a)
```

Usually this means look at the line above. You may be missing a semicolon or have too many or too few curly braces. Make sure that your curly braces line up exactly, and good code formatting and indentation will help you in doing this. By the way, your formatting is horrible and this is contributing to your not finding your errors.

This line: `Bank c[cust] = new Bank();` 
makes no sense whatsoever. what are you trying to do here?

Most important: read the tutorials and learn the basics. Add small amounts of code at a time and compile frequently. Don't add any new code until all compilation problems are solved, else you'll end up with nothing more than a rat's nest of errors.

Comment: Bank c[cust] = new Bank(); I am trying to create an array of classes...just like how we can create an array of structures in C. Is that the format? And can you tell me if there is an easier method to read numbers and strings instead of the Scanner class???

Answer (score 0):

Balance your braces, so you have the same amount of open and closing braces. 
That's usually the problem when you get `class or enum expected`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two closing braces

```
}  // <--
}  // <--
public static void Customer (String []a)
{
```

*and be prepared for different errors ..*

Answer (score 0):

The code is not well formatted, but my guess is that there is one or more unnecessary braces just before

```
public static void Customer (String []a)
```

The compiler is basically telling you that you are putting code outside of a class definition (or interface or enum) but that is not possible in java. All code must be inside a class (or interface or enum).